# How do I get the value of a column in a Pandas DataFrame with the name based on another columns value on the same row?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to create a new column in a DataFrame that looks like the picture that takes the value in the column with the same name as the value of the shipping_method column for each row.

So for example:

- row 0 would in the new column get the value of 57
- row 1 would get 126 (since "shipping_method" = "pm" and column "pm" = 126 on that row)
- row 2 would get 126
- row 3 would get 34

and so on...

Right now I'm solving this using melt() and then loc but this makes my dataset loose the dtypes witch I will have the add again and that is very slow for my dataset.

I've also been looking at lookup() but its deprecated so would rather avoid it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

[image: My DataFrame]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try via `numpy` with [`get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html#pandas-index-get-indexer):

```
df['new'] = df.values[df.index, df.columns.get_indexer(df['shipping_method'])]
```

More legible but slower via [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply):

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x['shipping_method']], axis=1)
```

Both Produce `df`:

```
  shipping_method   ps   pm  post  new
0              ps   57  126    60   57
1              pm   57  126    60  126
2              pm   57  126    60  126
3            post  500  350    34   34
```

---

DataFrame used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'shipping_method': ['ps', 'pm', 'pm', 'post'],
                   'ps': [57, 57, 57, 500],
                   'pm': [126, 126, 126, 350],
                   'post': [60, 60, 60, 34]})
```

---

Timing Information:

```
%timeit df.values[df.index, df.columns.get_indexer(df['shipping_method'])]
161 µs ± 4.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x[x['shipping_method']], axis=1)
449 µs ± 12.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

Without changing dtype by excluding the non-int columns from indexing:

```
# Select only columns with values
vals_df = df.loc[:, 'ps':'post']
df['new'] = (
    vals_df.values[vals_df.index,
                   vals_df.columns.get_indexer(df['shipping_method'])]
)
```

```
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

```
  shipping_method   ps   pm  post  new
0              ps   57  126    60   57
1              pm   57  126    60  126
2              pm   57  126    60  126
3            post  500  350    34   34
```

```
shipping_method    object
ps                  int64
pm                  int64
post                int64
new                 int64  # <- Correct dtype
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! I really liked the values approach but just like I commented on BENY's answer here is also changes the dtype from Int64 to Object witch requires me to change it back after witch takes a lot of time for the dataset I have now. With this in mind apply actually was faster since it for some reason doesn't change the dtype. Do you know a way to use the first function but without changing the dtype?

Comment: The only way would be to preselect the correct typed columns (the columns with the values) before. See the edit at the end.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! So type will always default to object of df dtypes are mixed?

Comment: Sort of. The column needs to have a single dtype. And the common dtype between strings and ints is object.

Answer (score 3):

As the doc recommend use `melt` for old [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) function

```
df['new'] = df.melt('shipping_method').query('shipping_method==variable')['value'].values
df
Out[143]: 
  shipping_method   ps   pm  post  new
0              ps   57  126    60   57
1              pm   57  126    60  126
2              pm   57  126    60  126
3            post  500  350    34   34
```

Comment: Thanks! This works just as expected, the only problem I have is that the new column gets dtype object even thought the "ps, pm, post" etc columns have dtype Int64. So when I runt this I have to change back the dtype after and this gets slow for a few million rows. Is there a way to do exactly this but preserve the dtype?